# How to convert dataframe column into list of lists json format?

Tags: python, pandas, list, to-json

My dataframe looks like below and I want to use sales column and convert it into json files for each month as a list of lists.

| sales | dt |
| --- | --- |
| 156 | 2022-01 |
| 192 | 2022-01 |
| 147 | 2022-02 |
| 192 | 2022-02 |

```
for date in date_range:
        df.loc[df['dt'] == date]['sales'].to_json(f"{out_path}/sales_{date.replace('-', '_')}.json", orient='values',indent=2)
```

Using this, I am getting this format of json files:

```
[
156,
192
]
```

However, I want to have:

```
[
 [156],
 [192]
]
```

I have created this as a toy example. I want to implement this on a very large dataframe for several months data. Can anyone point me how to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Libraries like `pandas` and `numpy` have methods to convert the data to native python objects such as lists. It might be something like `tolist`, `to_list` ...

Comment: @MSH, thank you for your comment. I tried using those but I want it to be converted into list of lists instead of just list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
    df = df.groupby('dt',as_index=False).agg({'sales':list})
    df['sales'] = df['sales'].apply(lambda x: [[e] for e in x])
    df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(row['sales']).to_json(
             f"{out_path}/sales_{row['dt'].replace('-','_')}.json",
             orient='values',indent=2), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you @SomeDude , for this simple and easy solution!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason of the single value in a array, but this code works:

***First cell:***

```
months_sales = []
sales = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if  [row["dt"]] in months_sales:
        index_month = months_sales.index([row["dt"]])
        sales[index_month].append([row["sales"]])
    else:
        months_sales.append([row["dt"]])
        sales.append([  [row["sales"]]  ])
```

***Second cell:***

```
for index, month in enumerate(months_sales):
   with open(str(month[0])+'.json', 'w') as f:
     f.write(str(sales[index]))
     files.download(str(month[0])+'.json')
```

You just need to change the path of the file (idk what environment/libs you are using).

The result is a file with the name of the 'dt' column, with the values. Ex:

```
   [
      [156], 
      [192]
   ]
```

edit:*
libs:

```
  import pandas as pd
  from google.colab import files
  import json
  import io
```